# Как переместить курсор мыши по координатам?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

Добрый день, как переместить курсор мыши например X = 400. Y = 700 вот по таким координатам.

Прошу мне помочь.

```
 private void start_game ()
    {
        Cursor.Position = new Point(400, 700);
    }

    private void FormLevel1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start_game();
    }
```

Comment: пробовали посмотреть в [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: да но плохо понял

Comment: @ильявитюк, нужно просто присвоить нужные координаты свойству `Position`

Comment: а можно как-нибудь на примере? я конечно сейчас сам попробую но все таки можете тоже мне пример привести?

Comment: из мсдн: `Cursor.Position = new Point(400, 700);`

Comment: Илья, лишние приветствия никак не помогают уточнить вопрос, а только служат информационным мусором )

Comment: вам наверно надо было не в коментах а в ответах написать

Comment: @Grundy что-то у меня не получается

Comment: @ильявитюк, без вашего кода ничего нельзя сказать

Comment: @Grundy на верху написал здесь не удобно

Comment: @ильявитюк, здесь специально сделано неудобно, чтобы исправления были в самом вопросе

Comment: Э-э... Теперь ответ сразу содержится в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Раз никто ответ размещать не хочет, придется мне.*

Свойство `Cursor.Position` возвращает и задает положение курсора. Конкретно в вашем случае нужно:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(400, 700);
```

Comment: @Grundy что-то у меня не получается что делать? Хотя ошибки никакой не выдает

Comment: вот что сам написал ` private void start_game ()
        {
            Cursor.Position = new Point(400, 700);
        }

        private void FormLevel1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            start_game();
        }`

Comment: @ильявитюк Во-первых - добавьте это в вопрос. Во вторых - проверьте отладчиком, заходит ли выполнение в этот метод

Comment: @Grundy проверил отладчиком он туда заходит но ничего не меняет

Comment: проверил отладчиком он туда заходит но ничего не меняет

Comment: Больше вы нигде курсор не трогаете? Тогда нет идей.

Comment: о круто,   черт и что делать

Comment: @ильявитюк Разбираться. Пробовать вызвать код несколько раз подряд. Из другого места. Вызвать и сразу же проверить положение курсора в коде, изменилось оно или нет. Проверять не переобъявлен ли у вас объект Cursor. Вобщем заниматься отладкой! )

Comment: ну ладно что смогли то сделали, @Kromster  спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: и @Grundy вам тоже спасибо за помощь