# Установить курсор в координаты

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте подскажите что мне надо сделать чтобы метод Cursor.Position() заработал (c#).

Желательно с картинками,заранее спасибо,я начинающий программист.

Вот  код:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
```

Comment: Код ваш приведите.

Comment: У вас проект winforms или wpf?

Comment: к сожалению нету сейчас прикреплю код

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApp28
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как переместить курсор мыши по координатам?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537572/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc)